# No brightness control in Ubuntu 12.04, Lenovo V570

Tags: 12.04, grub2, laptop, screen, brightness

I have been struggling now for an inordinate amount of time trying to get the brightness adjustment working in Ubuntu.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo V570 Laptop.

I have tried all of the adjustments I can find to "fix brightness control" in the `/etc/default/grub` file with the following results (before you ask, yes I did run `sudo update-grub` and `sudo reboot` after each change):

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

Result: No response to buttons, slider has no affect.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

Result: No response to buttons, slider has no affect.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"`

Result: Limited response to buttons from OS (slider only moves down one tick, then sticks), no dimming, slider has no affect.

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet"`
Result: OS responds to buttons, but screen does not dim.  Slider has no affect.

Am I missing something?  What can I do to adjust the brightness?

**Update:**
I did more searching, and I found that in `/sys/class/backlight` I have both `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight`.  By changing the "brightness" file in each of these folders, I discovered, that editing the `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` changed the actual brightness setting on my screen.
How do I get Ubuntu to adjust this setting?  Any hope of getting my function keys to also adjust it?

**Update2:**

As requested, here is the output from `lspci`:

```
    $ lspci | grep VGA
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my ThinkPad x240 running Ubuntu 14.04, and created a script that outputs and lets you step brightness up or down.

This assumes that the manual method of putting a number into /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight works, so test that first:

```
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<< 500
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness <<< 300
```

The script is here:

https://gist.github.com/emning/5d3301a3f3c9420414f7

Save it as 'brightness' somewhere in your path, make it executable and run:

```
brightness
brightness up
brightness down
```

You can also bind these commands to shortcut keys, even the standard brightness keys seem to work fine. I used Custom Shortcuts in KDE, but any desktop environment should work.

NOTE: For this to work when using shortcut keys, sudo without password has to be enabled for your user.

Answer (score 0):

I was also suffering from same problem,but I found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2198516) a solution that worked for me(on Acer Aspire-5738).

If you have `acpi_video0` and  `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` 
and changing `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` is changing your computer brightness  ,
you can force your system to use `intel_backlight`.

- Create a file `20-intel.conf` in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` using following command:

  `gksudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`
- Now paste this

  `Section "Device"
          Identifier  "card0"
          Driver      "intel"
          Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
          BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
  EndSection`
- Save and logout.

Comment: I just attempted this, to no avail.  After rebooting, I tried again to use the slider and the function keys to alter brightness.  Neither had any affect.

Comment: you can use `sudo tee sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` command temporarily to change your brightness using terminal or you can create a simple script having `#/bin/bash
sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, make it executable and use it until a working solution is not found..

Comment: Right, I am able to do it manually by using the method you mentioned.  Are you saying that it is not possible to use the slider and/or function keys at this time?

Comment: Can you post the output of `lspci  | grep  VGA`. `BusId` in the above solution may need to change according to output.

Comment: See 'Update 2' above.

Comment: changed the `etc/default/grub` GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""  ,then `sudo update-grub`,reboot and let me know.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to say there, but the settings that I currently have in `/etc/default/grub` are:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" and GRUB_CMD_LINUX=""
The behavior I have described is with those settings.